# How do I speed up Dark mode delay on website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to speed up dark mode taking effect on my website. When I load a page currently there is a delay between the page loading and dark mode taking effect. Here is my jQuery.js code

```
onload = function () {
  if (localStorage.getItem("darkMode") === "true") {
    var mode = localStorage.getItem("darkMode");
    enableDarkMode();
  }
}

function enableDarkMode() {
  $("body").addClass("dark");
  $("nav").removeClass("navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light");
  $("nav").addClass("navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark");
  $('.inner-switch').text("ON");
  var mode = localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "true");
}

function disableDarkMode() {
  $("body").removeClass("dark");
  $("nav").removeClass("navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark");
  $("nav").addClass("navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light");
  $('.inner-switch').text("OFF");
  var mode = localStorage.setItem("darkMode", "false");
}

$('.inner-switch').on("click", function () {
  if ($("body").hasClass("dark")) {
    disableDarkMode();
  } else {
    enableDarkMode();
  }
});
```

Comment: I have a feeling that removing the class navbar and adding it again triggers a lot of code behind you don't see.

Comment: Are you using an event to trigger your code? Like `$.ready()` or `DOMContentLoaded`? If you are using `window.onload` (which I suspect you are since you are assigning your function to the global onload variable), the script will run only after every DOM object has loaded.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

Comment: how about replacing `.addClass/.removeClass` with `attr("class", "[new class value]");` did you try it? **Edit**, oh, you were talking about page load. Then @blrzzzt and @Sonic1305 are both right.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a template engine like [Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/) and check for dark mode before even displaying the website. You could then assign a smarty variable and build an IF statement inside the HTML of the website.

Example:

```
<body {if darkMode} dark {/if}>
```

So it would be loaded with the dark mode activated from the very beginning.

Answer (score -1):

You need to know that:

- `localStorage.getItem();`
- `localStorage.setItem();`

are both synchronous processes which read from and write to the device's hard drive.

This makes them quite slow processes relative to most things you will run with javascript - and you can observe this effect, because, being synchronous, these processes need to finish before anything else in the javascript thread can run.

---

## Steps to take:

1) At the very least, I would replace `onload` at the start with `onDOMContentLoaded`.

2) Additionally I would also consider utilising another (faster) approach to persisting data between pages that isn't `webStorage`:

2a) **IndexedDB:** An optimal approach for storing state between pages is `indexedDB` **but** it is quite the convoluted API and not at all easy to get one's head around.

2b) **Cookies:** Old school but they work. Possibly overkill for this situation, though.

2c) **URL Query String:** One client-side option (quicker and easier than `indexedDB` and without the unnecessary extra back-and-forth mechanics of cookies) might be to use a query string like: `https://example.com/this-is/my-webpage/?mode=dark`

In this situation, I would probably use the third option immediately above, **URL Query String** in place of `webStorage`.

---

## The Future

For a couple of years now the web developer community has clamoured for a solution to persisting data between pages which has all the technical advantages of `IndexedDB` but is as simple to implement as `localStorage`.

Google has come up with a solution (*Keyword-Value Storage* or `KV Storage`) which is currently in experimental stages and will not be properly established in browsers (as a *built-in module*, no less) before 2020 or 2021:

Further Reading:

- https://css-tricks.com/kv-storage/

Comment: There's nothing inherently slow about web storage. It's cached in memory like everything else, it is not directly persisted to/from the hard drive. What makes you believe that cookies or indexed db would be faster?

Comment: I was given to understand that `IndexedDB` is asynchronous and doesn't slow down other processes (DOM manipulation etc.) unlike (synchronous) `localStorage`, which does.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: Perhaps I've been labouring under a false impression that localStorage is slow, clunky, synchronous and blocking. I've just read this (from 2015), which seeks to straighten the record: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/localstorage-is-fast

Comment: Are the performance concerns from 2012 (See: https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/03/there-is-no-simple-solution-for-local-storage/) exaggerated, then? If so (and I'm quite happy to be corrected), why is Google seeking to introduce `KV Storage`?

Comment: The performance concerns described in that article are for storing a lot large data, like folders of image files. For those, an asynchronous storage would be a better choice, but for the OP's use case of storing a simple boolean value, web storage is the perfect solution.

Comment: That alleviates some of my concerns, thank you. I will be interested to see if `KV Storage` ends up eclipsing `localStorage` or if it remains the latter's less well-known cousin.